# Powershell GUI script Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: user-interface, powershell, exchange-server

I've got a PowerShell GUI script that basing on the selected mailbox shows the folder statistics associated with that selected mailbox.

this is the code I have:

```
$buttonFolderStatistics_Click={
if ($combobox1.SelectedIndex -gt -1)
{

    $MailboxName = $combobox1.SelectedItem

    $textbox1.Text = (Get-Mailbox -Identity $MailboxName.Split('()')[1]) | Out-String
    $textbox1.Text = (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $MailboxName.Split('()')[1]) | Out-String
```

}

This part works fine:

```
$textbox1.Text = (Get-Mailbox -Identity $MailboxName.Split('()')[1]) | Out-String
```

This part crashes:

```
$textbox1.Text = (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $MailboxName.Split('()')[1]) | Out-String
```

This is the error message that I get: Get-MailboxFolderStatistics : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `$MailboxName`, ie. what's in the combobox?

Comment: Try adding `-AllowClobber` to your `Connect-ExchangeServer` command and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: @Mathias The content of the combobox is a list of mailboxes following this structure:

Mailbox Name (Alias) like Luis Patel (lu.pat)

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I am not using any Connect-ExchnageServer command, I am just using this add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 -ea silentlycontinue

Comment: I have noticed that if I run the script using PowerShell Exchange Console it works perfectly fine. Is there any way of making it to work using just normal PowerShell command line not the exchange one?

Comment: I can see the issue is that I am not connecting to the exchange server but I would like to know why I have to connect to it and why the first command works and the second doesn't

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's because some information is sync'd with Active Directory, but not all the gritty details. If you just want some basic mailbox info it can get that from AD. More detailed info would have to come from Exchange itself.